# How to use relational division?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, relational-division

I am creating a database using SQL, and right now I want to use relational division to search for things I want.  In this case, I want to know which players have all the icons.

```
CREATE TABLE OwnedIcon(PlayerID varchar(10) REFERENCES "Player" ("playerID"), IconID varchar(10) REFERENCES "Icon" ( "IconID"));

insert into OwnedIcon values('p001', 'icon001');
insert into OwnedIcon values('p001', 'icon002');
insert into OwnedIcon values('p001', 'icon003');
insert into OwnedIcon values('p002', 'icon001');
insert into OwnedIcon values('p003', 'icon001');
insert into OwnedIcon values('p003', 'icon002');
```

And then there is the `Icon` table

```
CREATE TABLE Icon(IconID varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, IconName varchar(15));
```

with the values:

```
insert into Icon values('icon001', 'beginner');
insert into Icon values('icon002', 'positive');
insert into Icon values('icon003', 'hunter');
```

What I thought was:

```
SELECT * from OwnedIcon, Icon WHERE OwnedIcon.IconID/Icon.IconID;
```

So only if you have all the icons, there would be a result.  So it should be player 1.

But it doesn't give me anything at all.

Comment: `inner join` on the id, that should leave you with only them?

Comment: Sorry but `WHERE OwnedIcon.IconID/Icon.IconID` makes no sense. `WHERE OwnedIcon.IconID/Icon.IconID = SOMETHING;` maybe makes sense, although I am not sure its legal syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your OwnedIcond table references player id twice which isn't what you want to do I'm assuming - your second reference should be to item id. Also, dividing to find who owns all icons isn't what you want to do,  you should be grouping players and icons and finding all players with the same number of icons as are in your db.

I'm on mobile but you want to do something like `select * from owned icon, group by player id having count = (select count(*) from icons)`

Comment: But isn't this possible with division then? It is more that I want to know how to do it since I never used division before and want to try it

Answer (score 0):

this makes sure you have at least one of each icon in icon table.
can a player have 2 icon001?

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT PlayerId,
       COUNT(DINSTINCT IconId) as IconOwned,
       IconCount
  FROM OwnedIcon,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(iconId) as Icons,
            COUNT(iconId) as IconCount
      FROM Icon)T
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(IconId,T.Icons)
  GROUP BY PlayerId
)T2
WHERE IconOwned >= IconCount
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1851cb/12)